# Why cookie is not preserved only in Chrome? Next.js / Express

Tags: javascript, express, next.js, cookies, authorization

I was creating my Next js app and faced the problem when switched to **chrome** form **safari**. In safari everything OK, cookie from server preserved on login action, but in chrome nothing.

My server settings:

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: config.get("frontendUrl"), //http://localhost:3000
    credentials: true,
  };

  app.use(cors(corsOptions));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(express.json());

 
  app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
  //other routes...
```

My login route(which should set cookies):

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {

  //validation...

  const accessToken = user.generateAccessToken();
  const refreshToken = user.generateRefreshToken();

  return res
    .cookie("accessToken", accessToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: config.get("isSecure"), //false
    })
    .cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: config.get("isSecure"), //false
    })
    .sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: I wonder if chrome doesn't accept cookie that are not https longer

Comment: Do you see the cookie header(s) in the HTTP response from the browser Network developer tab?